# Dativ und Genitiv genau umgekehrt verwendet

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, genitive

Die Genitiv-Flexion von "amerikanisch" ist "amerikanischen", die Dativ-Flexion ist "amerikanischem", siehe [hier](https://www.korrekturen.de/flexion/adjektive/amerikanisch/).

Aber man sagt z.B. "Wissenschaftler in amerikanische**m** Dienst", oder "Dieses Gebäude gehört amerikanischen Investoren". Das verwirrt mich, weil bei ersteren würde man fragen "In wessen Dienst?", also Genitiv, trotzdem nimmt man die Dativ-Flexion, im zweiten Beispiel würde man fragen "Wem gehört dieses Gebäude?", also Dativ-Fragemodus, trotzdem taucht in besagten Satz die Genitiv-Form auf.

Was ist die Erklärung dafür?

Comment: Mhh, okay, das könnte sein. Und bei Wissenschaftler? Ist ja auch plural, aber für den Plural gibt es keine Flexion mit "m"?

Comment: "Wissenschaftler" is Nominativ, hier haben Singular und Plural die gleiche Form.

Comment: Es geht um ein Adjektiv. Das ist Dativ wegen der Präposition "in", die hier den Dativ verlangt.

Comment: Hier geht ja alles durcheinander! Da *Investoren* im Dativ Plural steht, steht auch *amerikanischen* im Dativ Plural, also nicht Genitiv. Und auch wenn man *In wessen Dienst?* fragt, würden Adjektive, die vor *Dienst* stehen, denselben Kasus wie *Dienst* haben. Also Nominativ *amerikanischer Dienst*, Genitiv *wegen amerikanischen Dienstes*, **Dativ *in amerikanischem Dienst*** und Akkusativ *ohne amerikanischen Dienst*. Tatsächlich könnte man fragen: *In wessen amerikanischem Dienst? Dem der USA oder dem eines anderen amerikanischen Landes?*

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ähnlich verwirrt war ich als ich in deinem Profil "Non-additive vector space" gelesen habe, additiv = linear, "Non-Linear vector spaces" wtf, egal. Aber danke für die detaillierte Antwort!

Comment: @StefanH, dann empfehle ich Ihnen meine Dissertation, da klärt sich die Verwirrung auf :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wissenschaftler in amerikanischem Dienst

*amerikanischem* ist Dativ, ebenso wie *Dienst*, weil die Präposition *in* hier den Dativ verlangt. *Dienst* hat im Dativ keine Endung, daher kann man den Dativ hier nur erkennen, wenn man den gesamten Satz betrachtet.

> Dieses Gebäude gehört amerikanischen Investoren.

Das Verb *gehört* wird mit Dativ verwendet. Sowohl *amerikanischen* wie auch *Investoren* liegen daher im Dativ Plural vor.

Comment: Um das mal wieder mit den Frage-Wörter zu verbinden, also statt "in wessen Dienst" fragt man "in dem Dienst von wem"?

Comment: Es geht um ein Adjektiv, daher lautet die Frage rein formal *In welchem Dienst?*.